# 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called_once_with'

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to run the following test using pytest and pytest_mock

```
def rm(filename):
    helper(filename, 5)

def helper(filename):
    pass

def test_unix_fs(mocker):
    mocker.patch('module.helper')
    rm('file')
    helper.assert_called_once_with('file', 5)
```

But I get exception `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called_once_with'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can not perform a `.assert_called_once_with` function on a *vanilla* function: you first need to wrap it with the [**`mock.create_autospec`** <sup>[python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.create_autospec) decorator. So for instance:

```
import unittest.mock as mock

def rm(filename):
    helper(filename, 5)

def helper(filename):
    pass

helper = mock.create_autospec(helper)

def test_unix_fs(mocker):
    mocker.patch('module.helper')
    rm('file')
    helper.assert_called_once_with('file', 5)
```

Or more elegantly:

```
import unittest.mock as mock

def rm(filename):
    helper(filename, 5)

@mock.create_autospec
def helper(filename):
    pass

def test_unix_fs(mocker):
    mocker.patch('module.helper')
    rm('file')
    helper.assert_called_once_with('file', 5)
```

Note that the assertion will fail, since you call it only with `'file'`. So a valid test would be:

```
import unittest.mock as mock

def rm(filename):
    helper(filename, 5)

@mock.create_autospec
def helper(filename):
    pass

def test_unix_fs(mocker):
    mocker.patch('module.helper')
    rm('file')
    helper.assert_called_once_with('file')
```

**EDIT**: In case the function is defined in some module, you can wrap it in a decorator locally. For example:

```
import unittest.mock as mock
from some_module import some_function

some_function = mock.create_autospec(some_function)

def test_unix_fs(mocker):
    some_function('file')
    some_function.assert_called_once_with('file')
```

Comment: I wish SO had favourite answers and stars so I could click it & remember.

Comment: Problem here is that `helper` function may be defined in another module. I think that is not good idea add test stuff like `@mock.create_autospec` in application code.

Comment: @Overflow012: you do not have to do that. You can fetch the function from the module, and add a decorator over it locally.

Answer (score 5):

In **oriented object** case:

```
class Foo:
    def rm(self, filename):
        self.helper(filename, 5)

    def helper(self, filename, number):
        pass

def test_unix_fs(mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(Foo, 'helper')
    foo = Foo()
    foo.rm('file')
    helper.assert_called_once_with('file', 5)
```

Comment: should the final line be `foo.helper...`?