# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute in Pytest Mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, attributeerror

I am trying to test if my function is called inside the test, but I am getting:

**AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called_once'**

I am not mocking this correct, so could you please help me to find out why my mock does not work in this case. I have the right path to mock the function.

I have tried this -> [create_autospec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013672/function-object-has-no-attribute-assert-called-once-with) to solve the AttributeError, but no luck.

The code sample:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = {}

    def a(self, value):
        self._data = value

@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    return MyClass()

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_random_function(my_fixture, mocker):
    s = mocker.patch('path.module.a',
                              my_fixture.a)

    await random_function()
    s.assert_called_once()
```

Answer (score 0):

`my_fixture.a` in your test function is `MyClass.a` function which obviously doesn't have `assert_called_once`. That is a [method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_once) of `unittest.mock.Mock` and `unittest.mock.MagicMock`. I don't know why you are patching `path.module.a` with your own object but I think you would have hard time getting the same functionality that `MagicMock` provides. In your example I'd simply use the following.

```py
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_random_function(my_fixture, mocker):
    s = mocker.patch('path.module.a')

    await random_function()
    s.assert_called_once()
```