# Python3 mock replace function with another function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

How do I mock a function with another function in python, that will also provide a mock object?

I have code that does something like:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    r = bar(arg1)
    # does interesting things
```

I would like to substitute an implementation of the `bar` function, have it return sane values, and make sure it's called with the right arguments.

I've tried this, where `fake_bar` is my simple replacement for `bar`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def test_foo():
   with patch("x.bar", fake_bar) as mock_bar:
      actual = foo(arg1, arg2)
      assert actual == expected
      mock_bar.assert_called_once_with(arg1)
```

However, I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called_once'

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013672/function-object-has-no-attribute-assert-called-once-with) which suggests using create_autospec. However, mock.create_autospec does not preserve return values.

The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) suggests doing something like:

```
mock_function = create_autospec(function, return_value='fishy')
```

However, my faked version of `bar` has computed return values that are not static and not so simple to put into an inline lambda.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Is there a way to easily both mock a function and replace its implementation with something more complex than a static return value?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the `wraps` keyword argument:

```
def test_foo():
   with patch("x.bar", wraps=fake_bar) as mock_bar:
      actual = foo(arg1, arg2)
      assert actual == expected
      mock_bar.assert_called_once_with(arg1)
```

Here, `x.bar` is the fully qualified name of the function you are replacing, for example
'bigbusiness.account.AccountRepository.insert'.

`mock_bar` will still be a `Mock` (as is the default), but that `Mock` will wrap the function `fake_bar`, so the return value of `mock_bar` is the return value of `fake_bar`, rather than another `Mock` instance.

Comment: Nice, I found only one line in the docs that alludes to this and no examples

Comment: Also works with patch.object: patch.object(MyClass, "_MyClass__private_sum", wraps = lambda a, b: a+b)

Comment: @EzR1d3r You should avoid circumventing name mangling where possible.

Comment: @chepner No doubt that's true. But sometimes you have to.

Comment: Would you please show the definition of fake_bar to make this answer a bit more complete?

Answer (score 1):

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called_once

Sounds like you are trying to path with a regular function. 
Patch with a MagicMock object whose return value is the result of calling `fake_bar`.

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

def foo(arg1, arg2):
    r = bar(arg1)
    # does interesting things

def bar(arg):
    return 2

def fake_bar():
    #calculate 2!
    return 2

def test_foo():
    with patch("__main__.bar", MagicMock(return_value=fake_bar())) as mock_bar:
        arg1,arg2 = 'a','b'
        foo(arg1, arg2)
        mock_bar.assert_called_once_with(arg1)
##        mock_bar.assert_called_once_with('w')
        print(mock_bar.call_args)
```

---

Variants:

```
def test_foo():
    with patch("__main__.bar", autospec=True) as mock_bar:
        arg1,arg2 = 'a','b'
        mock_bar.return_value = fake_bar()
        foo(arg1, arg2)
        mock_bar.assert_called_once_with(arg1)
        print(mock_bar.call_args)
```