# pytest: unittest error object has no attribute 'assert_called_once_with

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, python-3.9, pytest-mock

I am writing unit test in pytest and getting error on assert_called_once_with.
I tired to use same way as been shown in the pytest documentation but seems I am missing something.

```py
# Class which I am trying to mock. (./src/Trading.py)
class BaseTrade:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Trade(BaseTrade):
    def __init__ (self, name):
        BaseTrade.__init__(self, name)

    def get_balance(self, value):
        # do calculation and return some value
        # for demo purpose hard-coding it
        return  value * 10


#unit test (./unitest/test_test.py
import mock
import unittest
import sys

sys.path.append("../src")

import Trading

class TestTradeClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        self.expected_balance = 100

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(self):
        pass
    def test_trade(self):
        with mock.patch.object(Trading.Trade, 'get_balance', new = lambda self, x: (x * 10) ) as mock_method:
            obj = Trading.Trade("AAPL")
            value = obj.get_balance(10)
            assert value == 100
        mock_method.assert_called_once_with(100)
```

```
Error on mock_method.assert_called_once_with(100)
  AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called_once_with'
```

Comment: Is `Trading.Trade` a class?  Is `Trading.Trade.get_balance` a method in `Trade`? e.g. `def get_balance(self, ...)`. Can you post the full class you're mocking?

Comment: Indent the last line to be inside the patching scope?

Comment: @hoefling Maybe, [this example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.create_autospec:~:text=As%20well%20as%20a%20decorator%20patch()%20can%20be%20used%20as%20a%20context%20manager%20in%20a%20with%20statement%3A) shows it outside of the `with` (I didn't know that was possible). Also, the error output looks like `mock_method` is binding as a variable, it's just that [`patch.object()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) isn't working.

Comment: @TonyN added classes which I trying to test. This test is just for demo purpose for a presentation.

Comment: @CrazyC thank you and keep cleaning up the `Trading.Trade` for us, if possible even make it runnable. The reason why is [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) is famous for being picky in what it patches.

Comment: @TonyN Now it's runable.
./src/Trading.py
./unittest/test_test.py

Comment: You can read about patch scope [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch). In short, you can try to `from Trading import Trade` and then patch accordingly `Trade`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now of the belief you want [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect). How is this? One file, assume `test.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import unittest

import mock


class BaseTrade:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Trade(BaseTrade):
    def __init__(self, name):
        BaseTrade.__init__(self, name)

    def get_balance(self, value):
        # do calculation and return some value
        # for demo purpose hard-coding it
        return value * 10


class TestTradeClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.expected_balance = 100

    def test_trade(self):
        # Without mock
        obj = Trade("AAPL")
        value = obj.get_balance(10)
        assert value == 100

        # With Trade.get_balance param patched
        with mock.patch.object(
            Trade, 'get_balance', side_effect=lambda value: value * 11
        ) as mock_method:
            obj = Trade("AAPL")
            value = obj.get_balance(10)
            assert value == 110
        mock_method.assert_called_once_with(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

`chmod +x test.py`

`./test.py`

Output:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Explanation:

- Use `side_effect` instead of `new`
- Combined to one file to make it easier
- removing `Trading.Trade`
- `@classmethod` to use `cls` and not `self`.
- `mock_method.assert_called_once_with(10)`, as `side_effect` cares about the value passed via `obj.get_balance(10)` and exists to alter the output.

Closer? If not can you clarify what you're trying to mock?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to tell, but if `Trading.Trade.get_method()` is actually a vanilla function and not a method - you may need [`unittest.mock.create_autospec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.create_autospec)

Are any of these of assistance?

- [`'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called_once_with'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48013672/1396928)
- [Python3 mock replace function with another function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59460964/1396928)

It's not clear whaat `Trading.Trade` is.

If by chance, `Trading` is a class that has a `self.trade = Trade(...)` inside, your question would be substantially different. You'd need to get in deeper, patching `Trade.get_method`, then. You'd likely want to import `Trade` from the same module `class Trading` uses it (e.g. `from .trading import Trading, Trade`) - *not* from where `Trade` is declared from - *then* patch the `Trade.get_method`.